# How to check if elements of a list are in a string

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement, element

The inverse of this question (finding a string in a list) is so popular, that I wasn't able to find an answer to my question.

```
black_list = ["ab:", "cd:", "ef:", "gh:"]

for line in some_file:
    if ":" in line and black_list not in line:
        pass
```

This obviously doesn't work. Some iteration over the list needs to happen that returns true/false, but I don't know how to accomplish that elegantly. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a regular expression or if by 'string' you're referring to a phrase, split it into an array and then see if you can match any of its elements ?

Comment: Can you give a short example of what input and output you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The builtin [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function can help you here:

```
black_list = ["ab:", "cd:", "ef:", "gh:"]

for line in some_file:
    if ":" in line and not any(x in line for x in black_list):
        pass
```

It's also possible to get the same effect with [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
for line in some_file:
    if ":" in line and all(x not in line for x in black_list):
        pass
```

... but I think the first is closer to English, so easier to follow.

Comment: Just what I was looking (hoping) for, nice and short.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for each "flag" within black_list, and filter lines that contain the black_list. This can be done using `all()`:

```
for line in some_file:
    filtered = all(i in line for i in black_list)
    if filtered and ':' in line:
        # this line is black listed -> do something
    else:
        # this line is good -> do something
```

The above checks to see if ALL of the elements of black_list are present. Use `any()`, if you want to reject a line if any of the elements of black_list are present:

```
for line in some_file:
    filetered = any(i in line for i in black_list_2)
    if filtered:
        # this line contains at least one element of the black_list
    else:
        # this line is fine
```

Comment: since the `in` operator always returns a boolean, `True if i in line else False` is a little redundant: for a given case, it's akin to saying `True if True else False` or `True if False else False`

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus, thank you I hadn't realised this. Will edit accordingly

Comment: Good point, @ZeroPiraeus. Though note that it's not really because `in` always returns a bool, but more because `any()` is defined to "return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable" -- in other words, `any()` does the equivalent of if/else.

Comment: @BenHoyt yes, there's that too :-)

Comment: Oh, and @NickBurns - on a closer look, your answer doesn't quite get it right: OP wants to check that ':' *is* in the string *but* none of the items in `black_list` are. Your solution checks that *both* ':' is in the string *and* all the items in `black_list` are.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code makes it look like you're looking for an element in a file, not just in a string. Regardless, you could do something like this, which illustrates doing both with the built-in `any()`function:

```
def check_string(text, word_list):
    return any(phrase in text for phrase in word_list)

def check_file(filename, word_list):
    with open(filename) as some_file:
        return any(check_string(line, word_list) for line in some_file)

black_list = ["ab:", "cd:", "ef:", "gh:"]

print check_file('some_file.txt', black_list)
```